# How to Extract Value in File1.csv to File2.csv where Column names are same in both Files

Tags: awk, cut

I Have datafile.csv with all columns

```
col1^col2^col3^col4^col5..^up-to col'n'
```

How do I read data of each line in extractfile.csv containing columnName^Value

> sampleData:

```
Row1:
col2^NY
col1^2017
col3^17:50
col5^Robert

Row2:
col2^NJ
col1^2015
col4^BMW|i8
col5^Cable,Mathew
```

and place value in datafile.csv under respective column
 where (**extractfile.csv[$columname]=datafile.csv[$columname]**)

> Expected Output:

```
col1^col2^col3^col4^col5..^col'n'
2017^NY^17:50^null^Robert^..^null^
2015^NJ^null^BMW|i8^Cable,Mathew^..^null^
```

*NOTE:* If there is no data for a column the field should be set to null in output.csv. Delimiter is ^.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide sample data for more than one row?

Comment: The question has been updated, thank you for your time.

Comment: Delimiter updated from ## to ^ for easier text processig

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"^" '
    NR==1{
        col=split($0,H)
        print
        next
    }
    /:$/{
        C[++i] = $0
    }
    NF > 1{
        D[C[i],$1] = $2
    }
    END{
        for(c in C)
            for(h in H)
                val = "null"
                if(D[C[c],H[h]])
                    val = D[C[c],H[h]]          
                if(h < col)
                    printf "%s" FS, val
                else
                    print val
    }
    ' datafile.csv extractfile.csv
```

produced

```
col1^col2^col3^col4^col5^col'n'
2017^NY^17:50^null^Robert^null
2015^NJ^null^BMW|i8^Cable,Mathew^null
```

Comment: Thank you for your time @Costas, unfortunately It only prints the first column and nothing further

Comment: Be sure that files format is not variate against noted in OP mesage

Comment: File format is .csv and delimiter is ^ now, please clarify

Comment: @Avin for you there is no difference `Row1:col1^2017` on 1 line or in two?

Comment: The order does not really matter as long as I get the corresponding values matched against the right label for each line block of data

Comment: @Avin I told you re format: do you see a difference between `Row1:col1^2017` and `Row1:\ncol1^2017` ?

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach. Call it with `awk -v RS="" -v n=6 -f myprog datafile.csv`:

```
BEGIN {
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        result = result "^col" i;
    }
    print substr(result, 2);
}
{
    delete data;
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        split($i, d, "^");
        data[d[1]] = d[2];
    }
    result = "";
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        value = data["col"i];
        if (value) {
            result = result "^" value;
        } else {
            result = result "^null";
        }
    }
    print substr(result, 2);
}
```